# Metodo Similar a Readline() para Windows Form?

Tags: c#

Quiero pasar un pequeño programilla que tengo creado en Console el cual coje el string que manda un dispositivo usb y lo manda por TCP a una IP y un puerto determinado.
Ahora mismo paso la cadena recibida a un `string` y lo trato a posteriori pero...
¿Que funcion/metodo tengo que utilizar para capturar lo que recibo por USB?

No me queda claro cual seria la mejor manera de hacerlo...
tengo lo siguiente...

```
    private void btnConectar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
                ActualizarStatus();
             try
            {
                envio.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(tbIP.Text), tbPuerto));
                ActualizarStatus();
                btnConectar.Enabled = false;

                while (true)
                {
                    Enviar(cadena);                
                }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                 ActualizarStatus(error.Message);
            }


    public void Enviar(string cadena)
         {
             ActualizarStatus();
             /////////////////////////////////////
             byte[] mensaje = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(cadena);
             try
                {
                    int bytesSent = envio.Send(mensaje);
                    ActualizarStatus();
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    ActualizarStatus(error.Message);
                }
          }
```

Si te fijas, estando dentro del metodo `Enviar()` necesito quedarme esperando en la linea donde tengo las ////////////////// a que el buffer del USB se llene, una vez tenga como dices el retorno de carro, seguiria con la siguiente linea, que me prepara el string `cadena` para enviarlo justo despues.
El problema que tengo es que no se como hacerlo de manera que no sea una chapuza.
Lo cierto es que en consola con un simple Console.ReadLine() soluciono todo...

P.D: He omitido parte del código por ser irrelevante para que no resulte pesado.

Gracias

Comment: No está muy claro como recibes los datos del USB, pero si es similar a `Console.Readline`(o sea,simula un teclado) habría muchas formas de implementarlo en windows forms, la mas sencilla un `TextBox`.

Comment: Imagina que es un teclado... necesito que cuando el puntero de programa pasa por esa linea se quede escuchando lo que meto por teclado, es decir, lo que me hace el Readline()...
No quiero un Textbox, necesito guardar lo que meto por teclado (o recibo del lector) en un string

Comment: Si no quieres un Textbox, pues simplemente usa el evento `KeyDown`o `keypress` del formulario.

Comment: No tecleo nada... Es un lector de código de barras. El funcionamiento de este es como si fuese un teclado, es decir, yo leo un código y me manda por USB la trama leida "ABCDE12345"
En consola, al hacer Readline() el programa se queda detenido en esa linea hasta que leo algo y el Readline() guarda la trama leida en el string que creo para ello, pero en WindowsForm no se que funcion utilizar para guardar la trama.

Comment: Es igual Edulon. Los lectores de códigos de barras son teclados que en lugar de teclas mandan las pulsaciones del código. Los eventos que te he dicho funcionan igual que si fuera un teclado

Comment: Gracias, lo pruebo y te digo

Comment: Bueno,al borrar tu respuesta se eliminó tambien mi comentario. Como te decía, prueba con lo que yo te he dicho y sustituye `ProcesarCodigo` por `Enviar`

Comment: Conseguido! Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No dispongo de un lector de código de barras ahora mismo, pero básicamente son exactamente igual que un teclado. Lo que yo haría es lo siguiente:

1. En el formulario, poner la propiedad `KeyPreview` a `true`
2. En el manejador del evento `KeyPress` vamos añadiendo los caracteres a una variable de tipo `string`.
3. Hay que detectar el final del código de barras. Esto normalmente es configurable en el lector, pero suele ser un retorno de carro. En el momento en es que se detecte el retorno de carro, deberías llamar a la función que trata el código de barras.

   ```
   string cadena = "";

   private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
   {
       if (char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) || char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
       {
           cadena += e.KeyChar;
       }
       else
       {
           if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
           {
               Enviar(cadena); //Como se llame tu método de procesado
               cadena = "";
           }
       }

   }
   ```